# Generate a random number of len(10) containing digits only 0-1s

Tags: python

The question is self-explanatory.

I've tried this.

```
import random

number = "".join([str(random.randint(0,1)) for i in xrange(0,10)])
print number
```

Is there any in-built functionality for the same?

Comment: Well: the best you can get is I imagine ''.join(random.choice('01') for _ in range(10))` - and avoid the int->str conversion...

Comment: There is `numpy.random.randint` but it's not built-in.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Either use:

```
''.join(random.choice('01') for _ in xrange(10))
```

Which avoids the int->str, or otherwise use `randrange` (to exclude a full bit set) with a range that's 2**10, then format as a binary string.

```
format(random.randrange(2**10), '010b')
```

Also, to avoid overflow, you can use `getrandbits` and specify 10 as the amount, eg:

```
format(random.getrandbits(10), '010b')
```

Comment: Beat me to the binary solution… :/ Classic Jon.

Comment: I think your second solution would be clearer with [`random.getrandbits`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.getrandbits)

Answer (score 1):

Choose a random int in the range 0 ti 1023 *inclusive* and format it in base 2 with a minimum width of 10 with leading 0s filled in.

```
format(random.randint(0,1023), '010b')
```

Comment: This produces string between length 1 and 11, rather than a string of length 10, always. `format(0, '0b')` produces `'0'`, `format(1024, '0b')` produces `'10000000000'`, and *half* of the possible numbers will produce 9 or fewer digits.

Comment: @MartijnPieters The idea of the answer, format an int in range(1024) with leading 0s added, is sound, but ghostbust555 was tripped up by randint including the stop value instead of excluding it, as range does.  He also forgot the field width.  I corrected both and the code now woks.  I consider this the best response to the OP's request for a 'builtin' solution.

Comment: @TerryJanReedy: it is very generous of you to correct the answer, but it is basically a *very late* and incorrect copy of Jon's answer (7 minutes later). In the process, the answer posted was also wrong; those small differences at this level counted.

Comment: @TerryJanReedy: note that Jon started with `randint()` as well, then corrected that to use `randrange()` to avoid the error.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Sorry, the Review page does not show the other answers and I did not read them carefully enough on the full page before editing.  I should have.

Comment: Use `random.randint(512,1023)` to get a number that's guaranteed to be 10 bits. since `512 = 2**9`

Answer (score 0):

I’m going to throw in another solution that creates an actual (decimal) number containing only ones and zeros:

```
>>> import random, functools
>>> functools.reduce(lambda x, i: 10 * x + random.randrange(2), range(10), 0)
1011001010
```

Comment: The output does not have 10 digits unless the first random digit is 1.

Answer (score -1):

OR, to skip the decimal-binary transition :

```
   from random import randint
   def repeat(n): 
    if(n<=0): 
      return '' 
    n -= 1 
    return str(randint(0,1))+repeat(n)
```

and at the end just call `repeat(10)` or whatever number of bits you want.